# having troubles with for loop array check and JSON variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops, for-loop

JS code

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$date = date('Gi', time());
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $(".show_hide").click( function()
       {
    var locTime = <?php echo json_encode($date) ?>; 
$.getJSON( "url_to_json", function(data) {
var isClosed = true;    
    for (var i = 0; i < data.location.monday.length || isClosed; i++) { 
    console.log("sucess1");
    xr_mon= data.location.monday[i];
    console.log("sucess2");
     if (locTime >= xr_mon.kai && locTime < xr_mon.guan ){
        console.log("location is open!");
        isClosed = false; 
        $('.xr').show("drop", { direction: "up" }, 400); 
        }
    else {
        console.log("location is closed");
        $('.xr').hide("drop", {
              direction: "down"
          }, 800);
    }
    }
});
       }
  );
});
</script>
```

JSON code

```
{ "location": 
{
    "monday": [
    {"kai": 700, "guan": 1400},
    {"kai": 1700, "guan": 2100}

    ]
}
}
```

After a several try with this loop sequence.

I still couldn't figure out why it's still looping though even when isClosed meets the condition. Did I miss anything in my code???

found my answer.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$date = date('Gi', time());
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $(".show_hide").click( function()
   {
var locTime = <?php echo json_encode($date) ?>; 
$.getJSON( "url_to_json", function(data) {

for (var i = 0; i < data.location.monday.length; i++) { 
console.log("sucess1");
xr_mon= data.location.monday[i];
console.log("sucess2");
 if (locTime >= xr_mon.kai && locTime < xr_mon.guan ){
    console.log("location is open!");

    $('.xr').show("drop", { direction: "up" }, 400); 
    Break;
    }
else {
    console.log("location is closed");
    $('.xr').hide("drop", {
          direction: "down"
      }, 800);
}
}
});
   }
);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is there something about this that's wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/a22CW/

Comment: i want the location div (.xr) to stay open if it's in the opening hours. but this scrip would just skip the first IF, and always return me the result from ELSE.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, (Edit: did was change to can) can you try to use '&&' instead of '||' in a loop condition?

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.location.monday.length && isClosed; i++)
```

EDIT2:
Because when it is 1800, loop will check first this: {"kai": 700, "guan": 1400} and condition will not return true, because 1800 is not within 700 and 1400.
On the second try {"kai": 1700, "guan": 2100} condition will return true, because 1800 is within 1700 and 2100.
So I suggested to edit your script [this way](http://jsfiddle.net/a22CW/5/). 
Is it what you wanted to accomplish?

```
var isClosed = true;    
    xr_mon= data.location.monday[0];
    xr_mon2= data.location.monday[1];
    if ((locTime >= xr_mon.kai && locTime < xr_mon.guan)  || (locTime >= xr_mon2.kai && locTime < xr_mon2.guan) ){
        console.log("location is open!");
        isClosed = false; 
        $('.xr').show("drop", { direction: "up" }, 400); 
        }
    else {
        console.log("location is closed");
        $('.xr').hide("drop", {direction: "down"}, 800);
    }
```

Comment: i want the value of hours between open and close not OR.

Comment: @user2510532 I was writing about a loop, not "if" condition. For clarification: Do you want to end up a loop when a locTime will be between open and close?